# I'm stuck at Script query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/new_population/_search -d '{

"query":{
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
       "term":{"message":"developer"}
    },
    "filter" : {
        "script" : {
            "script" : "doc['birth'].value > 20"
        }
    }
}
}
}'
```

but I'm getting the below error:

```
 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"new_population","node":"AEKkYpmhRuWEOTJo64WKhg","reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled"}}]},"status":500}
```

I have even changed "script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs": on in .yml file
Please help: I'm following this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html)

Comment: Yeah, enable dynamic scripting in ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting. The enablement is with `true` and `false` and restart of the nodes.

Comment: The message is self-explanatory, as well: `scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled` while you have enabled: `groovy.inline.aggs`. Do a bit of reading before posting every little issue you have.

Comment: The answer for this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345608/why-i-am-getting-error-while-executing-this-query-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable scripting through the below settings. Go in your elasticsearch folder->config-> elasticsearch.yml file and add this:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```