# Why I am getting error while executing this query in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

My query in ElasticSearch :

```
'filter':{              
  'script':{                
      'script':'_source.brand == \"samsung galaxy\"'        
   }        
 }
```

The error I get :

```
     {
          "shard": 0,
          "index": "test_database",
          "node": "yHIFcx8LQzCJHFYydcpdgA",
          "reason": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "status": 500
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in `elasticsearch.yml` and then restart your node. Add this to your configuration file:

```
script.inline: true
```

Comment: Did this help you?